# cs50 caesar - cypher not printing what is going wrong?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

Stuck on this problem. Codes compiles, and takes input. however when attempting to use key '1' with plaintext 'a', i'm expecting 'b' but returning "\001" (which is not printing) when i check the debugger. Can someone help me explain why this is happening? I suspect error is when im allocating memory for the cypher test.. or when actually doing the cypher in my for / if statements.

```
int main(int argc,string argv[]) 
{   
    check_commands(argc);

    //checks if key is alpha
    string key = argv[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(key[i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //convert string argv[1] into an int
    int k = atoi(key);

    //ask user for pplaintect
    string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext:  ");
    //create cyphertext variable
    int s = strlen(plaintext);
    char *cyphertext = malloc(s + 1);
    printf("Cyphertext: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                // cypher based of k but keep upper
                cyphertext[i] = ((plaintext[i] - 65) + k) % 26;
                //print uppercase cypher
                printf("%s", cyphertext);
            }

            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                //cypher based of k but keep lower
                cyphertext[i] = ((plaintext[i] - 97) + k) % 26;
                //print lowercase cypher
                printf("%s", cyphertext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
    free(cyphertext);
    printf("\n");
}

int check_commands(int argc)
{ //checks wether we have two command line arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1; //error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the main issue, but if the `else` ever gets hit you're not storing the value into `cyphertext[i]` so that spot will be whatever was in the uninitialized block of allocated memory. Seems like you should build `cyphertext` in the loop and print it once at the end.

Comment: `Usage: ./caesar key` is not a particularly useful message. I can see a user repeatedly invoking `../caesar g` and wondering why the progam isn't accepting `g` as a key.  If there are criteria the key must satisfy, the error message should provide details.

Comment: Is this for an assignment that requires CS50, or instead more casual self-learning?

Answer (score 0):

You're just putting the modulus into `cyphertext`. You need to add that to the first character of the alphabet to get the corresponding letter, just as you subtract the character before adding `k`.

```
                cyphertext[i] = 'A' + ((plaintext[i] - 'A') + k) % 26;
```

Also, don't hard-code ASCII codes like `65` and `97`. Use character literals.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated an uninitialized memory

```
char *cyphertext = malloc(s + 1);
```

It does not contain a string. So you may not use the conversion specifier `s` in calls of `printf` like this

```
printf("%s", cyphertext);
```

Also in these statements

```
cyphertext[i] = ((plaintext[i] - 65) + k) % 26;
```

and

```
cyphertext[i] = ((plaintext[i] - 97) + k) % 26;
```

you are storing not printable alpha characters.

Also this record

```
int s = strlen(plaintext);
```

is redundant.

Use do-while loop instead of the for loop. For example

```
size_t i = 0;

do
{
    if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )plaintext[i] ) )
    {
        // cypher based of k but keep upper
        cyphertext[i] = 'A' + ( plaintext[i] - 'A' + k ) % 26;
    }
    else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )plaintext[i] ) )
    {
        //cypher based of k but keep lower
        cyphertext[i] = 'a' + ( plaintext[i] - 'a' + k ) % 26;
    }
    else
    {
        cyphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
    }
} while ( plaintext[i++] != '\0' );

puts( cyphertext );
free( cyphertext );
```